# What should be defined as an en passant checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, history, terminology, en-passant

Is there a general consensus among composers, players, and/or organizations for what exactly defines an en passant checkmate, and is there any history  to it?

As far as I know, there are two possibilities to define it by.

1. The pawn captures, moving to deliver a discovered check that results in checkmate.
2. The pawn captures, and the *pawn itself* checkmates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I could not find  any "official" definition by a chess association/federation. This doesn't really surprise me, as there really is no need for a definition of "e.p. checkmate" to ensure correct play.

However the general internet consensus on the usage of the term seems to agree on the following requirements:

- The game has to end with checkmate.
- The last move has to be played en passant.

An exemplary notated move would be "**29... cxd e.p. #**" (although notating e.p. is optional under the *FIDE laws of chess (C.9)*) - regardless if the pawn capturing delivers check or not. The [Wikipedia examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant#Unusual_examples) follow this definition.

As there is no opinion by a regulatory instance about this topic, it seems to be up to you to make up your mind on this topic or bringing it to the attention of said regulatory instance. I am taking the "democratic" approach with the above definition.

Comment: I would be somewhat surprised if there was no official definition- at least the [WFCC](https://www.wfcc.ch/) or similar organizations could be expected to have some definition?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is defined at all.  But in your first case, the pawn is delivering the mate. So I think that would be the 'en passant mate'.  The 2nd case is 'just' a discovered mate.